# Set default function parameter equal to another field of that function

Tags: python, function, formatting

I was wondering if I could something like this in Python:

```
def func(val1,val2=val1):
    #do whatever you want
```

I could do the following:

```
def func(val1,val2=None):
    val2 = val1 if val2 == None else val2
    #do whatever you want
```

But is there a more efficient/sexier way to do it?

Edit: I don't think the linked question is close to what I am asking. What I am searching for is the right way to set a function's default parameter value to the value of another parameter

Comment: `if val2 == None else val2` => `if val2 is None else val2` apart from that you're good.

Comment: From a result point of vue, it doesn't change anything. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a parameter is None is done often in python where the parameter could be a mutable type.

By checking if none, it ensures that if the default type is a mutable type, an existing object isn't used.

tl;dr, what you have seems pretty pythonic to me.